# Since which level does buildDependents go into/up?

Tags: gradle

i asked me if task `buildDependent` would also build the dependents of the first level dependent project.

Aren't the further dependents transitive dependent to the initial project?

To better understand what i mean: D -> A <- B <- C

Projects B and D are first level dependents of A and C is transitive dependent.

So what happens if project A is invoked with `gradle buildDependent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test reveals that it does build `C`. Here's the result of `buildDependent` from `a` folder (filtered with `grep build`).

```
:a:build UP-TO-DATE
:b:build UP-TO-DATE
:c:build UP-TO-DATE
:c:buildDependents UP-TO-DATE
:b:buildDependents UP-TO-DATE
:d:build UP-TO-DATE
:d:buildDependents UP-TO-DATE
:a:buildDependents UP-TO-DATE
```